# AVCapture seems to lag, Text recognition doesn't start right away

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, firebase-mlkit

I am new to Swift and currently working on a feature which includes text recognition. I'm using the MLKit by Firebase and have the code, though it's not very sophisticated (I'm open for every suggestion to improve my coding), pretty much set up.

Anyways there are two things bothering me:

1. Since I've added the text recognition the live feed seems to lag (approx. 1 frame per second) - I reckon this one is somehow caused by the text recognition to prevent overload? If so, how to disconnect the live view and the frames which are processed?
2. The text recognition seems to start after 10 seconds. Is there away to make it start immediately?

CameraViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Vision
import FirebaseMLVision


class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {    

    private lazy var vision = Vision.vision()
    private lazy var textRecognizer = vision.onDeviceTextRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        captureSession()
    }

    func captureSession () {
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else{ return }
        captureSession.addInput(input)

        captureSession.startRunning()

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = view.frame

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {


        let metadata = VisionImageMetadata()

        let devicePosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back

        let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .portrait:
            metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .leftTop : .rightTop
        case .landscapeLeft:
            metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .bottomLeft : .topLeft
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .rightBottom : .leftBottom
        case .landscapeRight:
            metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .topRight : .bottomRight
        case .faceDown, .faceUp, .unknown:
            metadata.orientation = .leftTop
        }

        let image = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
        image.metadata = metadata

        textRecognizer.process(image) { result, error in
            guard error == nil, let result = result else {
                return
            }

            for block in result.blocks {
                for line in block.lines {
                    for element in line.elements {
                        let elementText = element.text
                        print(element.text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput**

```
output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
```

as in https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-ios/blob/master/translate/TranslateDemo/CameraViewController.swift#L307

Comment: Updated link to the above answer is here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-ios/blob/bf4a889d4c5f2b80585e3ddc3811c0da6c140a8d/translate/final/TranslateDemo/CameraViewController.swift#L298